# Validate form fields in controller with a hasMany relation

Tags: validation, cakephp

I'm having some issues with validating form fields inside my controller, for testing purposes.

I have my model `Experience` with hasMany `ExperienceDetail`. `ExperienceDetail` belongsTo `Experience`.

I created a form using the `FormHelper` which contains the following:

index.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Experience', array('action' => 'index'));
echo $this->Form->input('Experience.date', array(
        'label' => array(
            'text' => 'Datum'),
        'type' => 'date',
        'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
        'monthNames' => false,
        'minYear' => date('Y') - 10,
        'maxYear' => date('Y')
        )
    );      
echo $this->Form->input('Experience.test');
echo $this->Form->input('ExperienceDetail.vertrekstation');
echo $this->Form->end('Verstuur!');
?>
```

There are some more fields provided with `ExperienceDetail`, but these are irrelevant for this matter.

Experience.php

```
<?php 
class Experience extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Experience';

    public $hasMany = 'ExperienceDetail';

    public $validate = array(
        'vertrekstation' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Voer een vertrekstation in',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'test' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Test mag niet leeg zijn!'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

ExperienceDetail.php

```
<?php
class ExperienceDetail extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'ExperienceDetail';

    public $belongsTo = 'Experience';

    public $validate = array(
        'vertrekstation' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Voer een vertrekstation in'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

ExperiencesController.php

```
<?php 
class ExperiencesController extends AppController { 
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

public function index() {
    // $this->layout = 'default_orig'; 
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'De OV-Ervaringenmeter!');

    // LOAD Model Carrier 
    $this->loadModel('Carrier');
    $this->set('carrier', $this->Carrier->find('list', array('order' => array('Carrier.name' => 'asc'))));

    // Check if form is allready filled
    if($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->Experience->set($this->request->data);
        $this->Session->setFlash('No if or else statement is called');

        if ($this->Experience->validates()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Validates!');
        }
    }       

}
}
?>
```

The problem is: when I send the form and leave `test` empty, it provides me the validation error which I've set up in the Model. But when I leave `vertrekstation` empty, it doesn't provide me any errors that belongs to the input field.

What am I doing wrong and how am I able to get these errors printed?

Comment: You may try to validate the ExperienceDetail separately, like this; `$this->Experience->ExperienceDetail->validates()`, however, if you use `$this->Experience->saveAssociated()`, it *should* validate all data and insert/update all models in one go

Comment: OK, I found another thing, and I parsed `$this->validationErrors` to my view in debug mode, and that gave me the right validation errors back. But then, it doesn't show underneath the input fields. I'll try your solution as well. Thanks!